# Symfony repository created in the wrong place

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I was following the Symfony tutorial and was creating a repository for my product entity by hand and not using the console to create it. Originally the annotation looked like this:

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
```

but as I am learning to use the console to create the Entities and Repositories I have tried changing it so that it is in the correct place. The console placed all the console created ones in the Repository directory instead. My product entity now looks like this (changed by hand):

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
```

However when I issue this command

```
# php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

OR

```
# php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product
```

the repository ends up in the Entity directory, not the Repository one. I have looked up this issue and looks like Doctrine caches but I have tried the following commands to clear it with no luck:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

I have even tried recreating the Entity via the console but it continues to create the file in the wrong place. Occasionally it places it in the correct place for one refresh of the browser but then complains it cant find it (since it is looking for it in the Entity directory.

Anyone help me straighten out Doctrine? Here are my classes so you can see fully:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;  //<--- This is one of the issues. See answer

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    ...
```

[image: folder_structure]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone tried but didn't comment back on this, thanks to anyone who took time to look this over.

The answer was stupidity on my part. I created the project while I was logged in as root instead of the web user so the cached metadata files were not able to be overwritten. I found this out by running the following command:

```
# php bin/console cache:clear
```

and got ....

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The directory "/path/to/testapp/var/cache/dev/annotations" is not writable.
```

(path above modified to mask real path). Secondly the name of the namespace in my class was clearly wrong. It should have been:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;
```

Anyhow thanks.